Java, How to filter list?
How to filter/exclude the RuleDesc if the corresponding ruleID is any of these (ruleIdsToExclude = "Type1,Type2,Type3,Type4". How to exclude the ruleDesc's if ruleID matches with "Type1,Type2,Type3,Type4"
rulesList              ArrayList
  [0]                  RuleType
     ruleDescr         “test1”
     ruleID            “Rule1”
  [1]                  Ruletype
     ruleDescr         “test2”
     ruleID            “Type2”
  [2]                    RuleType
     ruleDescr        "test3"
     ruleID           "Type3"
  [3]                    RuleType
     ruleDescr        "test4"
     ruleID           "Rule4"
ruleList only contains test1 and test4 after excluding ruleID's Type2 and Type3.

private List<String> extractAlertsInfoList(RulesListType thisDetailRulesList) {
    List<String> alertsInfoList = new ArrayList<>();
    if (thisDetailRulesList != null && CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(thisDetailRulesList.getRule())) {
List<RuleType> rulesList = thisDetailRulesList.getRule();

for (RuleType thisRule : rulesList) {
     String ruleId = thisRule.getRuleID().toString().trim();
     String ruleIdsToExclude = "Type1,Type2,Type3,Type4";
   if (isValidRuleDescription(thisRule.getRuleDesc()) ) {
    alertsInfoList.add(thisRule.getRuleDesc());
                    }
               }
           }
         return alertsInfoList;
       }

       private boolean isValidRuleDescription(String ruleDesc) {        
           return ruleDesc != null && !ruleDesc.isEmpty();
       }

Thanks

You could use Stream<T> filter(Predicate<? super T> predicate):
List<String> toExclude = Arrays.asList("Type1,Type2,Type3,Type4".split(","));
List<RuleType> filteredList = thisDetailRulesList.getRule()
        .stream()
        .filter(rr -> !toExclude.contains(rr.getID()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());


Thanks Matheus. Its gving the error at toList(). The method toList() is undefined for the type stream 

@samd fixed, I've edited the code. biboo is probably correct. This error is happening because of your Java version
